# AWS ELB Redirection to main domain

Tags: amazon-elb

My one website is running behind aws ELB and some of my uses are using directly elb url and other are using main domain which is pointed to elb.

so i want to redirect my elb "http://rotary-staging-1821321305.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/" to https://staging.rotaryisu.com/rotary/frontend/web/site/login

Can anyone help me on this if it is possible..

Comment: what webserver are you running...?

Comment: Hi, I am using apache web server.

Comment: So you want to redirect your ELB to your DNS which redirects to your ELB?